# Why Java LogRecord constructor calls a random method to check non null parameter?

Tags: java, oracle, logging

The constructor of the class `java.util.logging.LogRecord(Level level, String msg)` explains explicitly in its code that in the first line invokes a random line of code to check that the variable `level` is not null.

> // Make sure level isn't null, by calling random method.

Are there some hidden explanations for this?

Here is a screenshot of the constructor but you can check it directly from your IDE.

[image: LogRecord]

Comment: it is not calling a *random* method in the sense that they method chosen is *randomly* selected it is just poorly worded and semantically incorrect

Answer (score 2):

It is just an example of an implicit null check.

Even though the comment says 'random method' the getClass() is chosen because:

1. It is shorter than writing an explicit if check for null and throwing a new NullPointerException. But on the other hand there is a long comment explaining the short code.
2. It is free of side effects.
3. It is declared final and can't be overridden by a subclass.
4. The code was written prior to [java.util.Objects.requireNonNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)).